# Get fullpath not working with file dialog

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code:

```
 Imports System.IO

Public Class Form2
Dim fileName As String = "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Visual Basic\Test\test.txt"
Dim pathname As String = "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Visual Basic\Test\test.txt"
Dim result As String

Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    fdTxtFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Visual Basic\Test"

    fdTxtFile.ShowDialog()
    ' fdTxtFile.
End Sub


Private Sub fdTxtFile_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles fdTxtFile.FileOk
    Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
    result = Path.GetFullPath(fdTxtFile.ToString)
    tbFileLocation.Text = result
    strm = fdTxtFile.OpenFile()

    ' tbFileLocation.Text = 
End Sub
End Class
```

However, when using Path.GetFullPath(), It opens the file dialog, I select the file and the ok button does nothing, with no errors. I'm trying to get it so that it displays the full file path of the selected file to a textbox, however this is bugging me. Other functions such as GetFileName() etc work, just this one does nothing on clicking OK.

Comment: What kind of control fdTxtFile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use the `FileOk` event, you could simply wait the return from `ShowDialog()` call  and read the value stored in the `FileName` property. If the user press the OK button the [ShowDialog returns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e61ft40c.aspx) a value equal to the `DialogResult.OK` enum value and you could work from there. Also the FileName property of the OpenFileDialog contains the full filename and thus there is no need to use the GetFullPath.

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    fdTxtFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Visual Basic\Test"

    If DialogResult.OK = fdTxtFile.ShowDialog() Then

        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
        result = fdTxtFile.FileName
        tbFileLocation.Text = result
        ....
    End If
End Sub
```

As a side note, the way in which you use the GetFullPath seems to be wrong. GetFullPath requires a partial file name and converting the OpenFileDialog to a string doesn't produce a filename

Answer (score 0):

If the [`FileOk` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.fileok.aspx), use the property [`FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx)  to access the selected file(s). If you have set [`Multiselect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect.aspx) to `True`, use [`FileNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames.aspx) instead.

> The file name includes both the file path and the extension. If no files are selected, this method returns an empty string ("").